# SQL Server: Get All foreign keys with one-to-one and one-to-many Relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to list out all foreign keys **together with their relationship types (1 to 1, or 1 to many)** in db in SQL Server? I know about the `EXEC sp_fkeys` stored procedure but it does not show the relationship type of the foreign key.

Edit:
I have also tried the following approach and I believe I can modify it in a way that I can also understand the relationship types, so any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KF ON RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME =         KF.CONSTRAINT_NAME
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KP ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = KP.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Comment: Do you mean one-to-one table and one-to-many table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below `JOINS` and `PARTITION BY` to achieve this,

```
SELECT 
    PKTableOwner, PKTableName, PKColumnName, FKTableOwner, FKTableName, FKColumnName,
    (
        CASE
            WHEN [Count] > 1
            THEN '1 to Many'
            ELSE '1 to 1'
        END
    ) AS RelationshipType
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(SYSNAME, SCHEMA_NAME(OP.SCHEMA_ID)) AS PKTableOwner,
        CONVERT(SYSNAME, OP.NAME) AS PKTableName,   
        CONVERT(SYSNAME, CP.NAME) AS PKColumnName,
        CONVERT(SYSNAME, SCHEMA_NAME(OFK.SCHEMA_ID)) AS FKTableOwner,
        CONVERT(SYSNAME, OFK.NAME) AS FKTableName,  
        CONVERT(SYSNAME, CFK.NAME) AS FKColumnName,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY OP.SCHEMA_ID, OP.NAME, CP.NAME) AS [Count]
    FROM
        SYS.FOREIGN_KEYS F
    INNER JOIN
        SYS.FOREIGN_KEY_COLUMNS FC
        ON
        F.OBJECT_ID = FC.CONSTRAINT_OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN
        SYS.OBJECTS OP
        ON
        OP.OBJECT_ID = F.REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN
        SYS.COLUMNS CP
        ON
        CP.OBJECT_ID = F.REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID
        AND
        CP.COLUMN_ID = FC.REFERENCED_COLUMN_ID
    INNER JOIN
        SYS.OBJECTS OFK
        ON
        OFK.OBJECT_ID = F.PARENT_OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN
        SYS.COLUMNS CFK
        ON
        CFK.OBJECT_ID = F.PARENT_OBJECT_ID
        AND
        CFK.COLUMN_ID = FC.PARENT_COLUMN_ID ) F
```